# Using LWJGL and Slick2d, how do I load up a large image(sprite sheet) and store it into smaller images?

Tags: lwjgl, slick2d

I have done a little bit of basic stuff, I can tiles a grass tile across the screen evenly, I can display a transparent texture to the screen but I can't seem to find any documentation on loading sprites from a larger sprite sheet.

How would I dice the image up into smaller images? Or is there a different way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [SpriteSheet class](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/SpriteSheet.html) in Slick that does exactly this.

SpriteSheets, in Slick, are large images made up of a series of uniformly sized tiles. Each tile is typically an animation frame in a Sprite. In the `SpriteSheet` constructor you specify the image (which has all the tiles), and the width/height of the tiles in the sheet, along with any spacing and margin, if you have/need that.

Finally, the `getSprite(x, y)` method allows you to retrieve the specified tile, as if it were an element in a 2D array. In other words, if you have a `SpriteSheet` of 16 tiles, that are arranged in a 4x4 grid of tiles, then to get the tile in column 3, row 2, you would call `getSprite(3, 2);`

I believe the indexes in `getSprite(x, y)` are zero-based, just like arrays in Java.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. You can only accept your own answer after 24 hours, I believe. It's perfectly acceptable to accept your own answer.

Comment: Yup. I figured, better someone else get the credit too. So that maybe more people will ask and answer more lwjgl questions.

Comment: the getSprite method has really bad performance when you are rendering a tiled map. you should use renderInUSe